# PHP function issues with array

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, web-deployment

I have a postgres table with four columns labelled dstart which is date data type,
  dend which is also a date data type, dcontract which is a date data type and id which is a integer. I am trying to run a php code to get the data using an array and use it in the body of my application. But when I test the array and try to echo some values... My browser just displays the word array...    Is there anyway I can be able to retrieve the data or fix this code? Please see code below

```
  <?php

  function getLiveDate($campid)
  {
        global $conn,$agencies;


         $return=array(
         'livedate'=>'',
         'campid'=>'',
         'enddate'=>'',
         'dateContract'=>'',         
        );

        $sql = "SELECT id, dcontract, dstart, dend 
        FROM campaigns 
        WHERE id = '".$campid."' ORDER BY dstart DESC LIMIT 1";

        $r = pg_query($conn,$sql);
        if ($r)
        {
                $d = pg_fetch_array($r);
                if (!empty($d))
        {

            $return['livedate'] = $d['dstart'];
            $return['campid'] = $d['id'];
            $return['enddate'] = $d['dend'];
            $return['dateContract'] = $d['dcontract'];
        }
        }
        @pg_free_result($r);

        return $return;
 }
```

Comment: You have 4 columns in 1 table with the same name?

Comment: our columns labelled dstart which is date data type, dend which is also a date data type, dcontract which is a date data type and id which is a integer. Meaning They are named dstart(date), dend(date), dcontract(date) and id(integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure, your array `$d` is "multi-dimensional" and `pg_fetch_array()` returns an array of arrays, because the result of SQL queries in general may contain multiple rows. You limited it to one row, but you certainly get the correct values by assinging `$return['livedata'] = $d[0]['dstart'];` or `$return['livedata'] = $d['dstart'][0];` and so on (I am not familiar with that particularly function for I usually use MySQL instead of Postgre).
Besides, try echoing your data by means of `print_r()` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Thanks this helped out a lot.. managed to get the issue sorted out :-)

Answer (score -1):

The $return variable is an array, if you want shows the content, you must use print_r or var_dump not echo.

Comment: This really doesn't answer his question and you don't know if he's dumping or echoing anything because the code doesn't show that, just what the function returns.